# Find ΔHr for HCl + Mg Reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I am having trouble calculating the value of $\Delta H_\mathrm r$ for the reaction: $$\ce{Mg + HCl}$$ The total heat capacity ($C_\text{cal} + C_\mathrm r$) is $6.88\ \mathrm{kJ/{^\circ C}}$, and the $\Delta T$ is $10.5\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$. When I multiply the two I get $72.24$ which is $Q_\mathrm r$ (Total heat produced). Finally when I divide $72.24$ and $0.005$ moles of $\ce{Mg}$ I get $14\,448\ \mathrm{kJ}$. This seems to me to be inaccurate. Can anyone help me solve $\Delta H_\mathrm r$